# How to skip eclipse validation of folders for building workspace(Luna Edition)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, workspace

I want to skip validation of some folders while building workspace. My eclipse spend half an hour every time validating this folders. So, I want no more validation for them.
I'm giving the screen shots of folders of my project I want skip. My eclipse mainly stuck in node_modules and vendor folder while validating workspace.

My project:

[image: My project]

Contents of problematic folders:

[image: Contents of problematic folders]

Comment: It s basically not validation the folders, But the files inside the folders.. Eclispse is an ocean. Anyone can contribute such ugly feature which will affect everyone. Now I want you to check which validation is triggered. Who executes it? May be take a thread dump will help you. They might have provided option to disable the validation in their preference page. If not, uncheck build workspace opion. No other go.

Comment: How can I figure that out? My validation only shows the folder it validating. Is there any way to find which validation it's triggering,so I can uncheck them? @karthikRocky

Comment: Have you heard of jvisualvm. It allows you to take thread dump of any java application. Open task manager. Check the process I'd of your eclipse. Open jVisualVM which is available inside java/bin folder. Right click and say thread dump. You will get a clue which thread is  getting  executed. Or you click on sample to see which class from which project takes more time... These steps are to identify who s running the analysis if validation nama s not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the problem because I tried to install Angular.js with bower in my project. I seems bower has lots of javascript files it downloaded automatically which caused my IDE to stuck in validation process for a long time. So, I solved this problem this way,

- I first installed tern.js 0.9.0.
- Then I went to the project properties, selected tern script path
  included only the path I needed for validation, My project's
  javascript folder. I excluded other path like placeholders,
  Angular.js files, Jquery files.
- I selected the Javascript from the properties again and did the same
  things in include path's source.

My IDE currently working without freezing. I took help from there. [Tern](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Performance)
I guess it can be helpful, where any IDE stuck due to lots of Javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

You may sometimes need to selectively **include** or **exclude** certain files or directories in an **Eclipse** project. For example, I had a data subdirectory in my Eclipse project with thousands of files. Eclipse would spend lots of time needlessly indexing these files. This can be prevented by just excluding that directory from the project.

1. Right-click on the project and choose Properties. Choose *Resource* ->
   *Resource Filters*.
2. In the **Resource Filters** dialog, click Add and choose which files and
   directories to either **Include Only** or **Exclude All**. Only provide the
   file or directory name, not a relative path or absolute path!
3. Refresh the project to update these settings. The excluded files or
   directories should disappear from the project.

https://codeyarns.com/2015/02/11/how-to-include-or-exclude-files-in-eclipse-project/